# Начала виснуть клавиатура/мышь

Tags: клавиатура, железо, мышь

Начала подвисать клавиатура (или мышь) пару дней назад.

**Суть проблемы:**

Две системы — линукс и винда. Дней 5 назад под линуксом зависла клавиатура, все остальное работало. Буквально позавчера заметил, что клавитура не работала при загрузке (не мог выбрать винду) загрузился дефаультный линукс. В нём всё работало. И понеслось. Не могу выбрать систему при загрузке. То же самое и в БИОСе — клавиатура сначала не реагирует на нажатие на клавиши, но потом одна "залипает". Интересно, что если отключить мышь, клавишу "попускает" и всё работает. Вновь подключил мышь — клавиатура опять залипла.

Пробовал менять порты подключения — не помогло.

При отключённой мыши всё работает и можно выбирать систему. Под линуксом/виндовсом, кроме вышеупомянутого случая проблем не возникало. Иногда всё-таки можно выбрать систему с включённой мышью.

БИОС — востанавливал значения по умолчанию — без результата.

Comment: А как Linux устанавливали? Собственноручно или через Wubi?

Comment: Сам ставил. Так было уже лет 8. Сначала ВинХР был, потом Семёрка. Обновлял/переустанавливал. Линукс постепенно обновлял (наверное с 17 и уже 27) Последний раз линукс обновлял месяцев 7 тому. Проблем до сих пор не было.
Ну и при чём линукс, когда клава в БИОСе виснет?